# Import-Excel for multiple sheets

Tags: excel, powershell

Using the `Import-Excel` module in powershell, can multiple sheets be referenced at once? Example:

```
Export-Excel c:\reports\reprt.xlsx -WorkSheetName "Sheet1, Sheet2"
```

Comment: How should ***Export-Excel*** determine what of the piped (or supplied via -InputObject) input is for what Worksheet?

Comment: Are you looking to put the same data on both sheets, have the system create a new sheet each time it hits the last row on the previous sheet, or export different content to each sheet?  You may want to look at `Export-MultipleExcelSheets`, though you'd need to create the InfoMap table according to your requirements; where each key is the worksheet name, and each value the data to be exported.  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.0.1/Content/Public%5CExport-MultipleExcelSheets.ps1

Answer (score 3):

Reading between the lines in your question, I assume you meant 'Import-Excel' or you'd have referenced data to export.
I tend to do it this way, utilising the 'Get-ExcelSheetInfo' function within the same module:

```
$AllSheets = Get-ExcelSheetInfo 'c:\reports\reprt.xlsx'
$AllItemsInAllSheets = $AllSheets | Foreach {Import-Excel $_.Path -WorksheetName $_.Name}
```

It's possible to transpose the '$AllSheets' variable to have a one-liner too for simpler lookups:

```
$AllItemsInAllSheets = Get-ExcelSheetInfo 'c:\reports\reprt.xlsx' | Foreach {Import-Excel $_.Path -WorksheetName $_.Name}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both Export-Excel and Import-Excel, it appears that the WorkSheetName parameter is type string and not an array or list that can contain multiple values. You could always download the source code and modify this parameter yourself. I would imagine that would take a lot of effort to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done, no need to know worksheet's name

```
Open-ExcelPackage -Path ".\TEST.xlsx" | Get-Member | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.MemberType -eq 'ScriptProperty'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | % {
$tempName = "$_"
$tempValue = "$(Get-Variable | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -eq "tempName"} | Get-Variable -ValueOnly)"
Remove-variable -Name "$($tempValue)" -Force -EA SilentlyContinue
New-Variable -Name "$($tempValue)" -Value (Import-excel -path ".\TEST.xlsx" -WorksheetName "$($tempValue)") -Scope Script}
```